# Enlarge clickable area of button

Tags: java, click, action

I have a Java applet which is running on a touchscreen monitor. I want to activate e.g. a button's action even when the user didn't hit it exactly. Maybe in a range of 5 pixel of the click, the nearest clickable object have to trigger his action.

How do I enlarge a button's hit area?

For example, if the size of a button is (width=100, height=25), the clickable area of this button should be a little bit larger than the button itself (width=120, height=45)

What I´m looking for is like TouchDelegate class from Android...
...Helper class to handle situations where you want a view to have a larger touch area than its actual view bounds...

Answer (score 1):

There is [padding](http://www.iraqtimeline.com/maxdesign/basicdesign/images/margin_padding.jpg) option for this purpose.
So if you use padding your button looks smaller than the actual clickable area.

Sorry I don't know how to set it in Java applet. Try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089098/java-awt-application-window-padding), I suppose `Insets` correspond to padding OR try this (like stated [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/345647/GUI/java/JButton-text-padding)):

```
button.setMargin(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
```

**Edit**
If you can use drawable resource to serve in place of a button there is another way - just make border transparent.

Comment: example to a JButton? I can´t find any code with padding

Comment: I tried button.setMargin(new Insets()); and button.addBorder(new emptyBorder()); but unfortunately both attempts are enlarging my buttons...

Comment: EmptyBorder -> Creates an empty border that takes up space but which does no drawing, specif... maybe no drawing but ironically it enlarges my buttons nevertheless ...