# Increase the hitbox of Circle in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating circles of size 5 with something like `Circle c = new Circle(x, y, 5);`. Then I do `c.setOnMousePressed(mousePressedEventHandler);` but I've got a problem here : my circle is too small and it's easy to miss it. I would like to keep this size so is there a way to increase the hitbox of a circle without doing something like creating an invisible circle bigger and then set the listner on it ?

Comment: Perhaps making a second larger `Circle` and rendering the first unclickable or putting it under the second one would do what you are looking for.

Edit: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233239/enlarge-clickable-area-of-button

Comment: @AustinSchäfer There's no padding or margin option for circle in JavaFX. And I would like to find a solution without creating a second larger `Circle` like I said. But if there's no other solution I would do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the hit area by adding a transparent stroke to the circles.

**Note:** To actually use hit *boxes* you need to set the `pickOnBounds` property to `true`.

```
private static Circle createCircle(double x, double y, double radius, double hitRadius) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, radius, Color.BLACK);
    circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
    circle.setStroke(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    circle.setStrokeWidth((hitRadius < radius) ? 0 : (hitRadius - radius));
    return circle;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Circle circle1 = createCircle(100, 100, 5, 20);
    Circle circle2 = createCircle(150, 150, 5, 20);

    circle1.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> System.out.println("clicked 1"));
    circle2.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> System.out.println("clicked 2"));

    root.getChildren().addAll(
            circle1,
            circle2
    );

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```