# Increase a hitbox on XYChart.Series in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've got an EEG data that is comprised of 24 channels and am trying to create a plot on which you can see all of this data.
[It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOJIa.png)

I created a method that checks which XYChart.Series was clicked and colours it blue and al of the others back to black:

```java
private void colorSelectedChannel(MouseEvent e) {
    if (selectedChannels.size() == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allChannelSeries.size(); i++) {
            allChannelSeries.get(i).getNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke: black;");
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedChannels.size(); i++) {
            selectedChannelSeries.get(i).getNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke: black;");
        }
    }
    e.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke:blue;");

  }
```

The problem here is that you really need to hit the right pixel in order for the mouseEvent to get the node. I want to enlarge hitbox of a the XYChart.Series.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352737/increase-the-hitbox-of-circle-in-javafx) but I think I can't use its solution, because I can't increase the stroke width of XYChart.Series as it is a line in itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully, now it is more understandable.